# Where is shared and final layout in the security Editor

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-client, editor-user-permissions

I want to let the editors change between `shared layout` and `final layout` in the `Experience Editor`, but currently, they can't view that option without adding a new role to them.
How can I grant access to that part using the security editor?

**Edit:** `Sitecore 8.1`, they have a custom version of `Sitecore Client Authoring`.

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: I would also add more detail to your question: what roles do they currently have, what role do you have to add to get them there, and as Rich said, what version.

Comment: I think this question is not about the role that is required to grant this permission, but whether that specific permission can be extracted and added to anther role / these users. Cmasterd can you confirm?

Comment: Yes Kasaku is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimal out of the box sitecore role that gives you such capabilities(considering no overrides were done) is `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing`

If you need to assign a role to your own custom role you can give read access over the buttons chunk beneath `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/Chunks/Layout Modes`

And the the actual tab sections are located beneath `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Advanced/Layout` where you should assign read permissions if they are not already assigned.

Comment: I don't want to add another role, I should be able to go to Security Editor and grant them permission.

Comment: @cmasterd In that case take a look into the core database. The buttons are located beneath /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/Chunks/Layout Modes. But it is usually going to be better to just inherit the role to the custom role you have.

Comment: @cmasterd forgot to mention that the actual section is located beneath  /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Advanced/Layout

Comment: That first part is what I wanted let me just test and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @cmasterd glad I helped ! :)